# How can I make my gear simulation in the BGE work?

Tags: game-engine, objects, physics, logic-bricks, constraints

[image]

I have the movement and rotation restrained properly, but the simulation is not behaving like it should. both objects are rigid body objects.
[image]

## How can I make my gear simulation work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This problem is caused by the moment and rotation restraints on the top gear. To fix this, I recommend removing them:

[image]

Now, if you run the simulation,

The top gear is responding to the collision with the bottom gear. This is progress. (smile! - it almost works)

[image]

We just need to get the gear to ignore translation, but still respond to rotation. This can be done using a rigid body joint.

[image]

Now, we need to apply the right settings to the joint.

[image]

This joint will allow no translation, and will only allow rotation along the X axis. But this joint works relative to another object. We need to put a stationary object in the *target* field.

A static cube will work. (any other static object should also work as well)

[image]

Now, we simply set that cube to be the target object.

[image]

The top gear will now have it's X,Y, and Z translation locked to the cube's position, and since it is static, it will not be moving. The top gear's Y and Z rotation is also locked to the cubes rotation, and since it is a static cube, it also will not be rotating. The last step (this is optional) is to paint it your favorite color.

[image]

Now we can test the simulation:

[image]

## Yay! it works!

Comment: It's pretty cool that the physics engine is able to simulate this, but it also seems like a big waste of computational power - usually a game would just hard-code the fact that the gears' rotational speeds are linked, and calculate them directly, instead of simulating collisions between all the gear teeth.

Comment: I know, this type of simulation would be for checking if gears actually line up and would actually work. There would be no point to ever actually calculate this for a game.

Comment: "(this is optional)"—[citation needed]! :)

Comment: Returned the favour again. Selecting the "favorite color" is definitely the best part ;) lol. Thanks for this great answer!

Comment: @poor um.. what favor?

Comment: returned the favor!